# Unable to upload large video file

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, file-upload

I am trying to upload large video file using file up loader in my asp.net project but unable to upload. I also made some changes in my `web.config` file but not working.
Video with small size is upload successfully but problem occur in large video file uploading.

```
 <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
     <pages validateRequest="false"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true"/>
    <machineKey validationKey="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890AAAAAAAAAA" decryptionKey="123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: How large are the files you are trying to upload - the limit above is set to 1GB which is not that large for video?

Comment: @Mick,  I am trying to upload video file of less than 800 MB size.

Answer (score 1):

`maxRequestLength` takes priority over `maxAllowedContentLength`, since its smaller.

Try increasing its value to `1073741824`.